# How to get the hyperlink to work in this jquery scrip

Tags: jquery

One of the genius guys on here, helped me with this jquery script, so I could stick a link into a specific spot on my page, but the weird thing is the link does not work.  The hyperlink appears on the page, in the correct spot, but when I click it - the link in the bar changes to include /#virtualtour, but the page does nothing.  I know the url that is appearring in the bar, after the click the link is correct because if I click on the url bar and hit returns, the page loads or in this case, the virtual tour loads.

Does anyone have any idea what is missing and or what I am doing wrong?  See script below:  Thank you in advance.

```
jQuery("<li><a href='https://www.examplelink.com/#virtualtour'>Becker VTour</a></li>").insertAfter('.main-footer__menu:eq(3) li:eq(2)');
```

Comment: If the link appears and the url changes when you click it... then it's working. `virtualtour` may not be a valid anchor, or there may be another script preventing the jump to the anchor, or maybe there's a script meant to animate the scroll that's not working. Very difficult to diagnose without seeing the whole page.

Comment: Does an element called "virtualtour" exist on the page? Also try opening the console and see what occurs

Comment: Hi Gabriel, Here is the scenario - say you are on google.com, then typed in https://www.yahoo.com, but DID NOT press enter.  This is what is happening.  So when i click the link, the new address shows, but nothing happens.  The anchor tag is correct(#virtualtour) because when after clicking the link, I go up to the url bar and click return, the vtour runs.

Comment: HI  luismiguelss:

Yes, #virtualTour element is on the page and runs, when I go to the url bar and click return.

Comment: Most likely you are handling the hashtag onload only and not on window.onhashchange. When you hit enter the page loads and your code reads the hash. But when you click on link, the page doesn't reload, only the hashchange is triggered.

Comment: I found a solution, in theory, but can't find the code and I may need to make this a separate question.  So, current code works as it does now and after it run, now I want to set the focus on the  urlbar, click return.  I don't see how to press return while in the urlbar.